# Are there stats on crossover of public beta users?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, statistics

I just noticed that Area 51 has statistics on follower and crossover commitment (how many committed/following users have committed/followed other proposals).  But I was wondering if this type of statistic exists anywhere for actual beta membership.

It's really just a curiosity; being active in one of the non-techie proposals, I've noticed that *some* fairly active users don't appear to have a history with SOFU/Stack Exchange, but I'm curious as to how many of the "quieter" users landed there from Google or some similar place and subsequently registered.

Are these stats available?  If not, could they be made available on Area 51?

<sub>(To clarify: I'm talking specifically about statistics on proposals with significant numbers of common members and what percent of members they have in common, along with the percent of beta users who don't have linked accounts on any other SE site.)</sub>

Comment: we did have this in one of the board meeting packages, I thought, but I looked and I can't find it. It was not as high as you might think, meaning, we are in fact organically playing the Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon game -- but we're only maybe 1 or 2 steps away ATM.